# Clear current FocusOwner (jTextfield)

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Developing an application in swing, just a little query :- 
I want to clear the current focus owner textfield using a button. It is possible to determine whether a textfield is the current focus owner or not using **isFocusOwner()** but **how to clear the textfield which is currently on focus**?

Thanks!!!

Comment: do you have more than one text field which could be cleared using the button?

Comment: Yes, I have six text fields and I want to clear the field which is in focus

Comment: You can monitor focus changes at a application global level using the KeyboardFocusManager, the problem you have is, when you click the button, the button becomes the current focused component ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able use a `TextAction`. A TextAction has access to the last text component that had focus. So then in the text action you just clear the text in the component. All the logic is fully contained in the one place.

Here is an example that demonstrates the concept of using a TextAction. In this case the number represented by the button is appended to the text field with focus:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NumpadPanel extends JPanel
{
    public NumpadPanel()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTextField textField1 = new JTextField(4);
        JTextField textField2 = new JTextField(2);
        JTextField textField3 = new JTextField(2);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add( textField1 );
        panel.add( textField2 );
        panel.add( textField3 );
        add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        Action numberAction = new TextAction("")
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JTextComponent textComponent = getFocusedComponent();

                if (textComponent != null)
                    textComponent.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setMargin( new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20) );
            button.setFocusable( false );
            buttonPanel.add( button );
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Numpad Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new NumpadPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your case instead of using the replaceSelection() method you would just use the `setText()` method.

Comment: **1.** When I manually write the code for getFocusedComponent(); it shows me an error and tells me to write a method for it, but as far as I know this is an inbuilt method, right?

Comment: **2.** But if I copy paste your code it does not show any error, can u help me out with that?

Comment: Yes the getFocusedComponent() method is defined in the TextAction class. Did you import the proper package?

Comment: `private void clear_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)      {
     JTextComponent textComponent = getFocusedComponent();
     if (textComponent != null)
         textComponent.setText("");
}`

Comment: This is the code I wrote, for my application, but still the error exists for getFocusedComponent

Comment: I specifically stated you need to use a `TextAction`. I gave you a working example of how to extend a TextAction, I don't know what more I can do. All you need to do is change one line of code in the example I gave you.

Comment: I do understand what you have mentioned,  and thanks for your effort but hence I am doing it in an IDE and my scenario is a li'l different I ws trying this. Newz got it now. CHEERS:-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear a `textfield` using the clicking of a button, you have to write the code to clear the `textfield` in the the `ActionListener` class's `ActionPerformed` method. This method is called when the button is pressed. But in order to press the button you have to get the focus from other component to this button. So in the method `ActionPerformed` you would get `false` to `textField.isFocusOwner()`.

My suggestion to overcome this problem is:

1. add focus listeners to these 6 text fields.
2. declare a variable say `lastFocused` as type `JTextField` in initialise it to `null` in the Class that you are implementing all these.
3. write the following code to the focusListerners Overridden methods

   ```
   void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
       lastFocused = (JTextField) e.getComponent();
   }

   void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
       lastFocused = null;
   }
   ```
4. now in the `ActionListener` overridden method write the following:

   ```
   void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(lastFocused != null){
           lastFocused.setText("");
       }
   }
   ```

I feel this should solve your problem.

Comment: @user4648976 did you check my solution did it work or are you still facing problems?

Comment: I had made a a loop manually checking for each JTextfield and validating'em. Although your answer worked for me, so taking it as an answer. Cheers :)

Comment: You might be able to use a `TextAction` which would simplify the code.