# JTabbedPane dynamically tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I am creating a kind of notepad who have a pane for line counter who tell me the position of line (it increments when I press Enter) and another pane for line and column counter (just like Notepad++ have). I wanted to add tabs, dynamically, so everytime I select "New" option, a new tab will be created. By default, my notepad starts with one tab opened, just like Notepad++ does. Lets call this tab, TAB1

- If I press "New" it will create a new tab, lets call it TAB2. Now we have TAB1 and TAB2
- If I press again "New" it will create a new tab, lets call it TAB3, so I will have 3 tabs now: TAB1, TAB2, TAB3.

Now if I want to select TAB2 to edit something in it, this is the point where my program is not working properly, because if I want to press enter to go on new line, it will not add a new line in TAB2, it will add a new line in TAB3. How can I fix this?

Here is the ActionListener , where I say what to happen if I press "New" from menubar. state() is the function where I do layout.

```
if(menuFileNew == e.getSource())
    {   
        state();        
            Action newline = new AbstractAction() 
            {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
               {
                    thisTextArea.setText(thisTextArea.getText()+"\n");
                   counter++;
                thisLineCounterPane.setText(thisLineCounterPane.getText()+counter+"\n");            
               }
            }; 
        thisTextArea.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0), NEWLINE);
        thisTextArea.getActionMap().put(NEWLINE, newline);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Maybe an "idiot" question, but do you have one instance of JTextArea per tab ?

Comment: I have 2 textArea instances. 1 for 1st Tab, and another one for any tab that I will add.  Since I want to to it dinamically, I don't know how to create individual textAreas. Is not an "idiot" question, don't worry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
thisTextArea.setText(thisTextArea.getText()+"\n");
```

You "new line" Action is incorrect. You are hardcoding the text area variable you want to change.

Instead your `Action` should extend `TextAction` (not AbstractAction). Then you can use the `getFocusedComponent()` method of the `TextAction` to get the text area that currently has focus.

For a simple example check out: [Clear current FocusOwner (jTextfield)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096025/clear-current-focusowner-jtextfield/30111540#30111540)

Also, that is not the way to add a new line character to a text field. Don't use the setText() method. Instead you should be using the `append(...)` method.

Although the real question is why are you creating this Action? Adding a newline to the text area is the default behaviour when you press the Enter key.

Comment: I needed it for line counter and line&column counter. I've been trying without keybinding, it didn't worked.. Thank you for your answer, it works now !!

Comment: @ClaudiuM,  `I needed it for line counter` - and what if a line of text is removed. You should be using a `DocumentListener` to listen for changes to the text in the Document. `...and line&column counter` - you should be using a `CaretListener` to listen for movements of the Caret in the text are. In both cases you can then use the [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) to get the information on number of lines and line/column location.

Comment: for line&column, indeed I used CaretListener, but for line counter, I didn't knew about DocumentListener. DocumentListener will automatically increment and decrement number of lines when I press Enter and Backspace?

Comment: @ClaudiuM, You can't rely on "Enter" and "Backspace" to keep a line count. What if somebody pastes text into the text area? What happens is somebody selects a block of text and deletes it? The DocumentListener just tells you when a change is made, you must then calculate the current number of line, which is why I gave you the `Text Utilities` link.

Comment: I am using your Text Component Line Number, I added your component, and I can compile my program and it counts my lines, but when I switch on Design in Eclipse, is gives me an error saying "WindowBuilder was not able to show the GUI". what can I do?

Comment: I don't use an IDE. I have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: My issue is that, if I use BorderLayout, is works, but if I put your TextLineNumber into a JScrollPane, I get this error. I need to put it into JScrollPane, because otherwise my TextLineNumber will not get a scroll..

Comment: The TextLineNumber was designed to be added to row header of the scroll pane. I can't guess why it doesn't work in your IDE.

Comment: It works now, but if I want to see design, here comes an error. I will fix that, don.t matter. Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: Do you know how can I get textArea from current selected tab? because everytime it gets textArea of last added tab

Comment: You must make sure your text area get focus every time you switch a tab in order for the TextAction to work properly. Maybe [Tabbed Pane Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/tabbed-pane-focus/) will help.