# How to add on text into current textfield at current cursor position (Java)

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to finish up a GUI calculator in Java, and have run across a problem in which I cannot figure out how to add text onto the end of current text within a textfield that the cursor is currently positioned at.

Here is a picture of the calculator.
[image]

I have completed the operation buttons on the left and right side columns, and now am trying to complete the action listeners for the numbers buttons. I want to get it so that when my cursor was in the left textfield and I click on a number button, it adds that number into the textfield, and the same for the right textfield. I've tried using focus functions but couldn't figure out a way to add the button input into more whichever textfield my cursor was last in.

`https://github.com/johnwaugh1/projects/blob/main/calculator`

I hope I have successfully linked my code above, and the action listener which I was currently working on was for the button a0, towards the end of my code.

I tried many approaches, mostly using if else statements combined with focus functions, but none was able to insert text into more than one textfield.

Comment: `textField.setText(textfield.getText() + text)` - I would use a `FocusListener` attached to each text field to monitor which gained focus last - this is going to be some what hazardous, because you have other controls which can become focused

Comment: You could also make use of [KeyboardFocusManager#getFocusOwner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html#getFocusedWindow()), but again, this might not give you the results you're expecting

Comment: Extend `TextAction` for the Action on your buttons. The TextAction allows you to query which text component last had focus. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30111540/131872 for a working example.

Comment: code outside this site doesn't exist because this is a community effort to build a knowledgebase useful for all - that is also future - readers: a resources that faded away over time is not over useful ;) Instead, write and add a [mcve] here, that demonstrates what you are after, what you tried and how your efforts didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a FocusListener to tf1 and tf2, and add text to tfLast.

Off the top of my head, something like this should work.

```
private JTextField tfLast;

FocusAdapter fa = new FocusAdapter() {
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
     tfLast = (JTextField)e.getSource();
   }
}
tf1.addFocusListener(fa);
tf2.addFocusListener(fa);
tf1.requestFocusInWindow();

. . . .

tfLast.setText( . . . . );
```